# Is there a way to run several consecutive lines in the system command window using python

Tags: python

I have the following line of commands used in sequence from the command window. 
cd path 1 && file.bat && cd path 2 && printfNav path3 > Testing.txt

Is it possible to have this done through python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `os.system()` method. You will need to `import os` into your python program and then using this method you can send commands to the terminal. The method takes in a string and acts as if you typed that into your terminal. For example `os.system('pwd')` would cause the terminal to print out your current working directory, and so on so forth with other commands.

Comment: `os.system` is deprecated. Don't suggest it.

Comment: subprocess.call() would be the more modern method, sorry about that. Further documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: I was able to get all the commands in a windows batch file and run that command. Thank you for answers.